# OCR(optical character recognition) should use client side or server side in web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, azure, pdf

I am going to scan a image and upload that in database . I am using mongodb for storing documents .There is requirement to search within file , that is possible if i use OCR . So should i use ocr in client side or server side . I am using microsoft Azure server . i have thought about my steps.

1) scan a file or images.

2) store a file in mongodb as pdf file.

2.1) OCR the scanned image and save it as PDF and upload it along with OCR results to the database.

3)Search keyword in the Database and get the image ID(s).

4)load the file back in viewer in pdf format.

so please suggest me best and easiest way to achieve my goal .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Best OCR I have used is [ABBY](https://www.abbyy.com/en-eu/)

You Should use the OCR in Server side, as the Client side will reduce the performance.
If you are developing mobile app,You must use it in server side. And also you need to maintain some credentials for OCR SDK like key, its safe if you use this in server side.

For Abby sample code [click here](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/code-samples/?icon)

To register in Abby [click here](http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/Account/Welcome)

You can also go with opensource Tesseract OCR which is pretty good [click here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr)

Comment: thanks . can you please give me a useful link . and more thing clear that please . is my above strategy points good way ? means i should ocr before uploading file in db .

Comment: Yes you need to use ocr before uploading to db.check this link http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/Account/Welcome

Comment: Complete Sample code in all programing language in this link http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/code-samples/?icon

Comment: all right . @Supraj v

Comment: If you find my answer useful, you can accept it as an answer

Comment: i have checked, ABBY is not free or open source .

Comment: You can check for Tesseract OCR which is opensource by google in this link https://github.com/tesseract-ocr

Comment: @Suparj thanks but  #Tesseract OCR has not GUI .

Comment: I have checked another OCR dynamsoft that seems best solution. and some more workaround is required for that .